# Can I get information about users from different domains with the google calender api?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-calendar-api

I am developing a web application.
A communication app for use within organization.(The image is an example)
[image]

Within that application, I want to see each user's google calendar appointments.

The prerequisites are as follows:
・ The domain of each user's google account is different
・ Some users are not linked to Google (calendar information of users who are not linked does not have to be displayed)

Can't I see the calendar information for users who may have different domains?

If I want to make such an app, which of api key, oauth client id, and service account should I use?

Comment: Can you share more information on the issue you are having and what have you done so far?

Comment: thanks.

I did the tutorial on node in the following way.

https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/nodejs

This allowed me to google authenticate with my browser and access my calendar information.

Second, I don't know how to get other users' calendar information when I access the web application in my browser.

Comment: You can get the calendar information of users from your same domain (if you are the admin) by using service account as mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/auth#perform-google-workspace-domain-wide-delegation-of-authority). Is that what you whant?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.

In my application, each user's email address has a different domain.

userA: test@aaa.jp
userB: test2@bbb.jp

Is the service account all right in this case?

Do I have to set userA and userB calendar access permissions in advance from the console?